# MongoDB - Use results of multiple fetch queries in one update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building a platform for students to give mock test on. Once the test is complete, a results are to be generated for them relative to other students who attempted the said test.

Report contains multiple parameters i.e. rank, rank within their batch, and stuff like average marks people got on the given test are updated.

To get each of this data, I need to perform a separate query on the database and then I got to update 1. the result of current user who attempted the test 2. the result of everyone else (i.e. everyone's rank changes on new attempts)

So I need to perform multiple queries to get the data and run 2-3 update queries to set the new data.

Given mongodb calls are asynchronous, I can't find a way to gather all of that data at one place to be updated.

One way is to put the next query within the callback function of the previous query but I feel like there should be a better way than that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all)

Example:

```
const initialQueries = []

initialQueries.push("Some promise(s)")

Promise.all(initialQueries).then(results => {
  // After all initialQueries are finished
  updateQueries()
}).catch(err => {
  // At least one failed
})
```

Comment: I am gonna try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [db.collection.bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).
It allows multiple document **insertions**, **updates** (by _id or a custom filter), and even **deletes**.

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
db.collection('tests').bulkWrite([
  { updateOne : {
    "filter" : { "_id" : ObjectID("5d400af131602bf3fa09da3a") },
    "update" : { $set : { "score" : 20 } }
    }
  },
  { updateOne : {
    "filter" : { "_id" : ObjectID("5d233e7831602bf3fa996557") },
    "update" : { $set : { "score" : 15 } }
    }
  }
]);
```

New in version 3.2.

Comment: No, I meant I need to query data from multiple queries and then use all of that data to update in one.